# how concatenate strings that are pathed to a function in bash?

Tags: string, bash, string-concatenation

I'm creating a script that is supposed to create jobs on a HPC (cluster). I have created a function that gets 4 variables and create a string from them:

```
startJob (){
    if [ $per -lt 10 ]; then
    folder=/storage/users/avityo/prog/0$1.$2$3
    else
    folder=/storage/users/avityo/prog/$1.$2$3
    fi
    echo $folder
}
```

In the result I get from this, there is a separation by commas

```
/storage/users/avityo/prog/00,.583,bfd,
```

How can I remove these commas?

**Edit:**
Judging from the answers and comment I got, I should have mentioned how I call this function I have realized I'm not calling the function in the right way. I was using this:

```
let count=0

for per in $(seq 70 -5 0); do
    for seed in {580..583}; do
        for c in {"fs","fd","bfs","bfd"}; do
            let count=$count+1
            startJob $per, $seed, $c, $count
        done
    done
done
```

removing the commas when calling the function fixed this.

Comment: Did you try removing them in the source strings?

Comment: please edit your question to show your sample input to your function. Good luck.

Comment: For completeness, you don't need the braces in the inner for loop, either. `for c in "fs" "fd" "bfs" "bfd"; do` or even `for c in fs fd bfs bfd; do` will work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling your function like this:

```
startJob 0, 583, bfd, 4thUnusedArgument
```

You don't need the commas; the arguments are only separated by whitespace. Try this:

```
startJob 0 583 bfd 4thUnusedArgument
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to edit the source of the commas, so to say, you can just pipe it to sed.

```
echo $folder|sed 's/,//g'
```

Which will output

```
/storage/users/avityo/prog/00.583bfd
```